# Can't install kivy on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, kivy, cython

I am having trouble installing Kivy on by raspberry pi. I have raspberry Jessie installed and I was following the guide on the Kivy website but I keep getting the error Cython not compiled.

I have Cython 0.21.1 installed. I have read that I may need to install 0.20 but I have tried this but it does not install.

any ideas what I can do. I have searched the net but still have not found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

try `pip install Cython==0.23`. I think the best option is to follow the installation instruction given in Kivy's official website.
https://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/installation.html